# Maximizing the function $f:O(3,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $$A=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1 \vec{c} & \alpha_2 \vec{c}& \alpha_3 \vec{c}\end{pmatrix}, ~~\|\vec{c}\|=1, \vec{c}\in \mathbb{R}^3$$ Is fixed.
Let $$f:O(3,\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}, ~B\mapsto \mathrm{trace}(A^tB).$$ I want to find out the set $$\mathcal{S}=\left\{ B\in O(3,\mathbb{R}):~ B \text{ is global maxima of } f  \right\}.$$

**Edit**
Let me clear the problem by an example: If we take $2\times 2$ matrix and rank $1$ of the same type, i.e., $A=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1\vec{c}& \alpha_2\vec{c}\end{pmatrix}$, with $\|\vec|c\|=1,$ then there are exactly two matrices whose distance from $A$ is same. So basically I want to find out all the orthogonal matrix whose distance from the rank one matrix (in the above form, i.e., all the columns are non zero) is the same.

I hope the problem is clear, otherwise please comment so that I can clarify it more.

Comment: Consider this question: among all $\vec c = (c_1, c_2, c_3)$ with $\|c\|=1$, which one maximizes $\alpha_1 c_1 + \alpha_2 c_2 + \alpha_3 c_3$? I bring it up because your question is effectively the same. I'm changing $c$, while you are changing the coordinate system under which $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are defined.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get your point.

Comment: Each $B \in O(3,\Bbb R)$ corresponds to an orthonormal coordinate system on $\Bbb R^3$ (with fixed origin). Instead of thinking of this as holding $\vec c$ constant and changing the coordinate system, you can think of it as holding the coordinate system constant and changing $\vec c$. My variant is easy to solve. Think of the $\alpha_i$ correctly, and the answer becomes obvious. The translation back to your problem is not exactly 1-1, but once you know my answer, it is easier to figure out yours.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, but still it is unclear to me. What I am getting from your comment is,
I should change the problem from finding out the distance from fixed rank one matrix to $O(3)$ to find out the distance from fixed $B\in O(3)$ to space of all rank one matrices of the above type.

Comment: No, I told you to first solve the problem of finding the $c$ with $\|c\| = 1$ which maximizes $\alpha_1c_1 + \alpha_2c_2 + \alpha_3c_3$. Then i told you that this would be *very helpful* to solving your problem, which is in fact closely related.